# Probability of monkey writing word BANANA

Tags: probability

We put a monkey in front of a typewriter. At each instant $n$, the monkey picks at random a letter from the alphabet ($26$ letters) and then writes the letter.What is the probability of the monkey writing the word BANANA at least once? What is the probability of the monkey writing the word BANANA an infinite number of times?

I have no idea how to solve this problem so I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "At each instant"? Do you mean that the monkey types one letter for every instant in time (meaning that it types infinitely many letters in any given nonzero length of time), or does it type at a finite rate? Does the monkey continue typing for an infinite amount of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we only consder the independent(!) possibilities of the wird BANANA occuring within the first six letters, or within the second six lettres (i.e.,m positions 7 to 12), or within the third six letters (13 to 18), or ..., then we note that it occurs aeady  in each of these positions with a constant positive probability $p=\frac1{26^6}$. The probability that the word does *not* occur within the first $6n$ letters is therefore at most $(1-p)^n$. By letting $n\to \infty$, we see that the probability that BANANA does not occur at all in the infinite letter sequence is zero. By the same argument, for any fixed $m$, the probability that the word occurs at most $m$ times within the first $6n$ letters tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, i.e., the probability of at most $m$ occurrences in the infinite string is zero. Consequently, the probability of infinitely many occurrences is one.

Answer (score 0):

$1$ and $1$ if $n$ approaches infinity this is because an infinite amount will be typed on a finite charecter set. Each finite word will then be repeated infinitely in the sequence.

See : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem

Side note a bunch of grad students actuality did this with amusing but useless results.

Comment: "Link-only" responses should be posted as comments, not answers.

Comment: @probablyme I edited it to make it better?  I was looking for a list rules for what is and not an answer? can you provide a link?

Comment: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) You can also search the help center or meta for questions regarding answers and how this site works overall.

Comment: @probablyme 404 page not found, and I tried. don't really feel like posting to meta though, I feel this answer is satisfactory.

Comment: Please provide a solution to the problem for a better answer!!

Answer (score 0):

See the Borel Cantelli lemma, as this is a direct consequence. The probability that the monkey will not type the complete work of shakespeare is a finite subset of the sample space, and thus of measure zero. This is where the "almost surely" comes from, probability is still 1 by the property of measures.